# Windows Phone 7 Calendar programmatic access

Tags: windows-phone-7

Is there any way to interact with the Windows Phone 7 calendar?

I have some basic goals of reading from and writing to the calendar and I'm not sure there is a way to do this.

From what I can vcard and ical support are not even there.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The current release of Windows Phone 7 does not allow developers to build applications that interact with the Calendar ([see this thread](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/en-us/windowsphone7series/thread/1B7645B7-8348-40C9-A508-07D31A16A7AE)). At this stage, as lukas suggested, you need to roll out your own controls and services to synchronize with Google Calendar, Outlook, etc. You can also look at integrating your application with Live Calendar ([see MickN's links in this thread](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/windowsphone7series/thread/cd514558-2032-4e3c-b0ee-7e6a5a4d896e))

HTH, indyfromoz

Comment: Hi CJ, There may be some progress possible with those links I researched for the OP in the thread Indy linked. Unfortunately the OP didn't come back, so not sure how that went. Would be interesting to see if any results are possible here. Best of luck with that.

Answer (score 4):

The latest(as of August, 2011) release of WP7, codenamed Mango and WP7.1, DOES allows a read only access to calendar and contacts data.

Best way is to listen directly from horse's mouth. Check out the documentation at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh202972%28v=VS.92%29.aspx

Answer (score 1):

Im not 100% sure but it is not avaible for now.

Just some free thoughts: Maybe you can interract with a google or outlook calendar in your app via webservices and your user will have the synchronization between the phone calendar and web calendar so maybe this is the way, but I'm just thinking :)

Comment: Yes I also do think that is the way to interact with the Calendar-provider of your choice.